# Access to Google Drive Spreadsheet from remote Server

Tags: java, oauth-2.0, google-api, spreadsheet

I have client/server application. The server side must access a Spreadsheet on my own Google Drive.I make a test class to try to access to the spreadsheet list:

```
package com.eng.app;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.Authenticator;
import java.net.PasswordAuthentication;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.security.GeneralSecurityException;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Properties;

import com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.Credential;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredential;
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.json.JsonFactory;
import com.google.api.client.json.jackson2.JacksonFactory;
import com.google.gdata.client.spreadsheet.SpreadsheetService;
import com.google.gdata.data.spreadsheet.SpreadsheetEntry;
import com.google.gdata.data.spreadsheet.SpreadsheetFeed;
import com.google.gdata.util.ServiceException;

public class TestGoogleCredential {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException,
            InterruptedException, GeneralSecurityException, URISyntaxException, ServiceException {

        List<String> SCOPES = Arrays
                .asList("https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds");

        final HttpTransport TRANSPORT = new NetHttpTransport();
        final JsonFactory JSON_FACTORY = new JacksonFactory();


        File cert = new File(Credential.class.getClassLoader()
                .getResource("<the_file>.p12").toURI());

        HttpTransport transport = new NetHttpTransport();
        JacksonFactory jsonFactory = new JacksonFactory();

        GoogleCredential credential = new GoogleCredential.Builder()
                .setTransport(transport)
                .setJsonFactory(jsonFactory)
                .setServiceAccountId(<email-address>)
                .setServiceAccountScopes(SCOPES)
                .setServiceAccountPrivateKeyFromP12File(cert).build();

        SpreadsheetService service = new SpreadsheetService("Inertia");
        service.setOAuth2Credentials(credential);


        String urlString = "https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/spreadsheets/private/full";
        URL SPREADSHEET_FEED_URL = new URL(urlString);

        // istantiate the feed to the spreadsheets
        SpreadsheetFeed feed = service.getFeed(SPREADSHEET_FEED_URL,SpreadsheetFeed.class);

        // the list of all spreadsheets
        List<SpreadsheetEntry> spreadsheets = feed.getEntries();


        System.out.println(feed.getEntries().size());

        // select the particular spreadsheet on Inertia Ontology
        for (SpreadsheetEntry spreadsheetEntry : spreadsheets) {
                System.out.println("founded");
        }

    }
}
```

But when I run the code the size is 0 and no spreadsheet is printed out.

I have also make another test coding a program that access (on localhost) the Spreadsheet list using my Google Credential instead the OAuth2 authorization and it works well (it prints out all my spreadsheet on my Google Drive).

```
service.setUserCredentials(username, password); //My personal Google Account
```

NB: when I deploy on a remote server the test-program with My personal Google Credential (not OAuth2), it was blocked by Google for security policies.

Please any ideas?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

try to modify this snippet

```
GoogleCredential credential = new GoogleCredential.Builder()
                .setTransport(transport) 
                .setJsonFactory(jsonFactory) 
                .setServiceAccountId("google-dev-console-email-address") 
                .setServiceAccountUser("your-gmail")
                .setServiceAccountScopes(SCOPES) 
                .setServiceAccountPrivateKeyFromP12File(cert).build();
```